Find the residues at the isolated singularities of $\frac{z^2}{(z^2+1)^2}$
Find the residues at the isolated singularities of $$f(z)= \frac{z^2}{(z^2+1)^2}$$
We note that
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\frac{z^2}{(z^2+1)^2} = \frac{z^2}{(z+i)^2(z-i)^2}
\end{split}
\end{align}
And so we have singularities at $z=i$ and $z=-i$. I think it can be said that $f$ is analytic everywhere except $z= \pm i$. If that's the case, then $f$ is analytic on the punctured disk $0<|z-i|<1$. By Cauchy's Residue Theorem, we know
$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=i} f(z)= \frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_C \frac{z^2}{(z+i)^2(z-i)^2} \hspace{0.1cm} dz$$
Is this a good start? If so, what can I do from here? If not, what should I do instead? Thanks.

First of all, what are the orders of these poles? For each order, there is a formula for the residue.

Assuming that $C$ is the closed curve forming the boundary of the disk, wrapping once around the singularity in the positive (counterclockwise) direction and not enclosing any other singularities, then yes that integral gives you the residue. But you're thinking about it backwards. The residue is usually easier to find by other means (e.g., limit formula or familiar Laurent series) and can then tell you the value of the integral.

Thanks to the link posted in the comments, we have

$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=c}f(z) = \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \lim_{z \to c} \frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}} ((z-c)^nf(z))$$

Observe that $\frac{z^2}{(z^2+1)^2}$ has poles $z=\pm i$, both which are of order $2$. By the formula,
\begin{align}
    \begin{split}
        \mathrm{Res}_{z=i}f(z) &=  \lim_{z \to i} \frac{d}{dz} \left[(z-i)^2 \cdot \frac{z^2}{(z+i)^2(z-i)^2}\right] \\ 
        &= \lim_{z \to i} \frac{d}{dz} \left[ \frac{z^2}{(z+i)^2} \right] \\
        &= \lim_{z \to i} \frac{(z+i)^2 \cdot 2z - z^2 \cdot 2(z+i)}{(z+i)^4} \\
        &= \lim_{z \to i} \frac{2z(z+i) - 2z^2}{(z+i)^3} \\
        &= \lim_{z \to i} \frac{2zi}{(z+i)^3} \\
        &= -\frac{1}{4i^3} = \frac{1}{4i} = - \frac{i}{4} 
    \end{split}
\end{align}
